# Very challenging directive - looking for guidance on how to unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I just realized that none of the tests I have written for my directive are working in a way that actually tests anything so I am rewriting them. Problem is I cant figure out a way to test the link functions.

If anyone has a suggestion I would really really appreciate it.

Thanks for looking

```
angular.module('pb.webSites.directives')
    .directive('pbOrganizationImagePicker', [ function () {

        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: '<img data-ng-src="{{ imageSource }}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" alt="Image Picker" class="img-rounded" />',
            scope: {
                fileId: '=pbFileId',
                defaultSrc: '@pbDefaultSrc',
                width: '@pbWidth',
                height: '@pbHeight'
            },
            controller: 'pbOrganizationImagePickerController',

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('defaultSrc', function (value) {
                    if (value !== undefined) {
                        scope.imageSource = value;
                    }
                });

                element.on('click', function () {
                    scope.pickImage().then(function (image) {
                        scope.imageSource = image.storageUrl;
                        scope.fileId = image.fileId;
                    }, function () {
                        console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Someone asked what I was doing so far to test this directive. Right now the link sections tests are a mess but I thought I would post it here in case anyone else was curious.

```
describe('pbOrganizationImagePicker', function () {

    beforeEach(module('pb.webSites.controllers'));
    beforeEach(module('pb.webSites.directives'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.bootstrap'));

    var compile;
    var scope;
    var html = angular.element('<pb-organization-image-picker data-pb-default-src="{{ webSite.profileImageUrl || \'/content/img/placeholder-lg.jpg\' }}" data-pb-file-id="webSite.profileImageId" data-pb-width="200"></pb-organization-image-picker>');

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        compile = $compile
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));


    beforeEach(inject(function ($q, $injector) {

        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/app/webSites/directives/OrganizationImagePicker.html').respond(200, '');

        scopeObject = {
            profileImageUrl: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12345?s=40&d=identicon',
            profileImageId: 54634
        };

        scope.webSite = {
            profileImageId: 6436
        };

        scope.pickImage = function () {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            defer.resolve(scopeObject);
            return defer.promise;
        };

    }));


    describe('template with profileImageUrl', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            scope.webSite.profileImageUrl = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12345?s=40&d=identicon';
            element = compile(html)(scope);
        });

        it('should render HTML based on scope correctly', function () {
            expect(element.isolateScope().width).toEqual('200');
            expect(element.isolateScope().fileId).toEqual(scope.webSite.profileImageId);
            expect(element.isolateScope().defaultSrc).toEqual(scope.webSite.profileImageUrl);
        });
    });

    describe('template without profileImageUrl', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            element = compile(html)(scope);
        });

        it('use default URL if there is no  profileImageUrl', function () {
            expect(element.isolateScope().defaultSrc).toEqual('/content/img/placeholder-lg.jpg');
        });

    });

    describe('element.click()', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            var html = angular.element('<img data-ng-src="{{ imageSource }}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" alt="Image Picker" class="img-rounded" />');
        });

        it('should assign value to scope variables', function () {
            template = compile(html)(scope);
            template.triggerHandler('click');
            template.scope().$apply();
            scope.pickImage();
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.imageSource).toEqual(scopeObject.profileImageUrl);
            expect(template.isolateScope().fileId).toEqual(scopeObject.profileImageId);
        });

    });

    describe('$watch', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            element.isolateScope().defaultSrc = 'foobar';
            element = compile(html)(scope);
        });

        it('should have expected watchers added to the child scope', function () {
            expect(element.isolateScope().$$watchers[0].exp).toBe('defaultSrc');
        });

        it('$watch should watch for changes on defaultSrc', function () {
           element.isolateScope().defaultSrc = "barfoo";
           element.isolateScope().$apply();
           expect(scope.imageSource).toEqual('barfoo');
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: What are you doing to test the rest of it?  :-)  It seems like you could make the click function something on the controller -- Then you just need to get a reference to the controller in the test and you can call the click function without needing to simulate any click events or whatever.  As for watching, you can just change the value and use `$rootScope.$apply()` and IIRC, it should fire the watch callback.

Comment: its a bit embarrassing to share but I posted the test I am working on above if you are still curious. I like your idea about how to do the test the click. I will see if I have better luck doing it that way

Comment: Still no luck with this. If anyone has any other ideas please let me know! thanks!